# Does it harm anything to include an Entity in a transaction twice?

Tags: jpa-2.0, eclipselink

I am currently programming a tricky update task, where individual Entity objects might be updated more than one time in an atomic transaction.   My merge operation looks like this (omitting the **try** / **catch** for clarity):

```
@PersistenceContext protected EntityManager   em;
@Resource           protected UserTransaction utx;    
...
utx.begin();
for (Record r : listOfRecords) em.merge(r);
utx.commit();
```

If there are multiple references to a given Entity in the list, does anything bad happen?

This is with EclipseLink 2.3.2 as the JPA provider.

Answer (score 1):

**Persistent Context :** A persistence context is a set of managed entity instances in which for any persistent entity identity there is  a unique entity instance. Within the persistence context, the entity  instances and their lifecycle are managed by the entity manager.

**merge() :** Merge the state of the given entity into the current persistence context.

Therefore, there will exist only one instance of an entity at a time in the persistent context. So even if you update your entity multiple times, it will be reflected into database only once, when the transaction commits.